# How can I mask json using json-masker for fields with "-" in it?

Tags: node.js, json, logging

My requirement is to mask certain fields of a JSON while logging them.I am working on node.js. I have used json-masker library of node.js. While passing the JSON path of attributes with "-" in the name in the "whitelist" parameter, I am getting lexical error.

JSON

```
   {  
   "attribute1":"value1",
   "attribute2":"value2",
   "attribute-name":"value3"
   }
```

Code

```
const masker = require('json-masker');
const mask= masker({
whitelist: ['$.attribute1','$.attribute-name']
});
```

Error

```
    Error Lexical error on line 1. Unrecognized text.
    $.attribute-name
```

Also, is there a way to specify only the attributes that needs to be masked rather that specifying the ones that need not be masked(as specified in whitelist).
Please suggest if there is a better approach to do this using any other function/library.

Please note that I am receiving this JSON , so I cannot change the key name

Comment: can you review the answer @Pooja ? leave a comment if it didn't work for you, or mark it as accepted if it worked

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `'$["attribute-name"]'` instead of `'$.attribute-name'`

The `$` fields are processed by [jsonpath](https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath), a dependency of json-masker. This issue is discussed in one of their github issues ([#90](https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath/issues/90)) and the solution presented there.

Answer (score 0):

Use maskdata npm module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/maskdata

You can mask json fields containing '-' without any extra effort. Also, you can mask the nested fields too.

Example:

```
const MaskData = require('./maskdata');

const maskJSONOptions = {
  // Character to mask the data. Default value is '*'
  maskWith : "*",

  // It should be an array
  // Field names to mask. Can give multiple fields.
  fields : ['level1.level2.level3.field3', 'level1.level2.field2', 'level1.field1', 'value1'] 
};

const nestedObject = {
  level1: {
    field1: "field1",
    level2: {
      field2: "field2",
      level3: {
        field3: "field3",
      }
    }
  },
  value1: "value"
};
const maskedObj = MaskData.maskJSONFields(nestedObject, defaultJSONMaskOptions2);

//Output : {"level1":{"field1":"******","level2":{"field2":"******","level3":{"field3":"******"}}},"value1":"*****"}
```

Comment: it doesnt work for nested fields..any workaround you have ?

Answer (score 0):

const MaskData = require('./maskdata');
this version is deprecated don't use

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).